# XSLT to split XML based on value of node

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

I'd like to split a XML based on a value of a node via XSLT 3.0 transformation.

```
<SalesOrderRequestRequest>
<SalesOrderRequest>
    <ProcessingTypeCode>ZO03</ProcessingTypeCode>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000004</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>RE</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000004</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000003</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>WE</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000003</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000004</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>Y1</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000004</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000001</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>Y1</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000001</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
</SalesOrderRequest>
</SalesOrderRequestRequest>
```

The desired output is:

```
<SalesOrderRequestRequest>
<SalesOrderRequest>
    <ProcessingTypeCode>ZO03</ProcessingTypeCode>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000004</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>RE</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000004</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000003</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>WE</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000003</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000004</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>Y1</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000004</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
</SalesOrderRequest>
<SalesOrderRequest>
    <ProcessingTypeCode>ZO03</ProcessingTypeCode>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000004</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>RE</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000004</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000003</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>WE</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000003</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <InternalID>1000001</InternalID>
        <RoleCode>Y1</RoleCode>
        <RecipientERPPartyID>1000001</RecipientERPPartyID>
    </Party>
</SalesOrderRequest>
</SalesOrderRequestRequest>
```

So splitting the XML in 2 parts based on //Party/RoleCode = 'Y1'.
The idea is to leave everything unchanged, just XML split by multiple XML based on how many RoleCode = 'Y1' is encountered
Can anyone help me providing an example of XSLT transformation that should do the trick?

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid XML document, because if contains _two_ top-level elements. Or do you want a separate XML document per Party with RoleCode `Y1`?

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports - see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153.

Comment: Sorry, the example I provided is an extract of a larger XML document.
Assume there's another top-level element. The structure is actually
<Top-level>
<SalesOrderRequest>
...
</SalesOrderRequest>
<SalesOrderRequest>
...
</SalesOrderRequest>
</Top-level>

Comment: Please edit your question and the include code snippets to show the top-level element. Is in both the input and the output(s)? Also clarify what splitting means in this case, getting several result documents or just a single one in which the original data is restructured?

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for you answer. I have edited the question adding the top-level element. So the output is still nested under the top-level item. In my case, splitting means that the transformation should restructure the XML document and not creat different documents. Hope this clarifies. Thank you again Martin

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="Party[RoleCode = 'Y1']">
    <xsl:result-document href="split-{generate-id()}.xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="split-element" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="split" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="Party[RoleCode = 'Y1']">
    <xsl:param name="split-element" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$split-element is .">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online fiddle example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-skip%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Party%5BRoleCode%20%3D%20%27Y1%27%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20href%3D%22split-%7Bgenerate-id%28%29%7D.xml%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%2F%22%20mode%3D%22split%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22split-element%22%20select%3D%22.%22%20tunnel%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aapply-templates%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20name%3D%22split%22%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20mode%3D%22split%22%20match%3D%22Party%5BRoleCode%20%3D%20%27Y1%27%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22split-element%22%20tunnel%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22%24split-element%20is%20.%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3CSalesOrderRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CProcessingTypeCode%3EZO03%3C%2FProcessingTypeCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CInternalID%3E1000004%3C%2FInternalID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoleCode%3ERE%3C%2FRoleCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRecipientERPPartyID%3E1000004%3C%2FRecipientERPPartyID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CInternalID%3E1000003%3C%2FInternalID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoleCode%3EWE%3C%2FRoleCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRecipientERPPartyID%3E1000003%3C%2FRecipientERPPartyID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CInternalID%3E1000004%3C%2FInternalID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoleCode%3EY1%3C%2FRoleCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRecipientERPPartyID%3E1000004%3C%2FRecipientERPPartyID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CParty%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CInternalID%3E1000001%3C%2FInternalID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoleCode%3EY1%3C%2FRoleCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRecipientERPPartyID%3E1000001%3C%2FRecipientERPPartyID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FParty%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FSalesOrderRequest%3E%0D%0A&input-type=XML).